# Issue moving database between servers (cannot find .frm file even though it's there)

Tags: mysql, myisam

I used MAMP on my local machine to make a little site with a mysql database. I moved all the site files over the to server. Great.

The name of my database is roster and it has one table called users. I copied the 'roster' folder which contains the following files:

```
db.opt
users.frm
users.MYD
users.MYI
```

I put the 'roster' folder in the mysql directory. I run the following:

```
<?php
$db = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password") or die ('Fail message1');
mysql_select_db("roster") or die("Fail message2");
?>
```

No error. Awesome. But when I run the following:

```
$query = "SELECT last_name, first_name, u_name, skype_id, primary_location FROM users";

$result = mysql_query($query)or die('query error'.mysql_error());
```

Then I receive the following error:

```
query errorCan't find file: './roster/users.frm' (errno: 13)
```

Furthermore, when I login to the server and login to mysql. I see the database and table:

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| phones_db          |
| roster             |
+--------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> use roster;
Reading table information for completion of table and column names
You can turn off this feature to get a quicker startup with -A

Database changed

mysql> show tables;
+------------------+
| Tables_in_roster |
+------------------+
| users            |
+------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from users;
ERROR 1017 (HY000): Can't find file: './roster/users.frm' (errno: 13)
mysql>
```

I checked the 'roster' folder and it contains the four files mentioned at the beginning of this post. The file is where it supposed to be, right? Did I move the database wrong? What gives? Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## PROBLEM

You have a file permission issue.

The INFORMATION_SCHEMA database will not notice when doing just `show tables;` because it will scan for the `.frm`'s existence. It's when the storage engine attempts to access the physical files (`.MYD` and `.MYI') that mysqld will complain. All physical files of any table must have` mysql`as its owner. When the error says`Can't find file: './roster/users.frm' (errno: 13)`, it really means it cannot find the table's physical files with proper file permissions.

## SOLUTION

Change the owner of the roster folder and its contents to mysql.

## GIVE IT A TRY !!!

Comment: +1 Also disable SELinux.  SELinux frequently reports errors in file locations, permissions, etc. as "file not found."